# Problem using OnTriggerEnter2d() in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have recently followed a tutorial by bendux on wall sliding and on wall jumping.
I have copied his code, and made a few small adjustments to the rigidbody such as gravity, and the jumping power.
When the character is against a wall though, holding the input that moves you twoards it sort of sticks the player against the wall, and doesn't let it smoothly move down.

Here is the code for the player:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    public float speed = 8f;
    public float jumpingPower = 16f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private bool isWallSliding;
    private float wallSlidingSpeed = 2f;

    private bool isWallJumping;
    private float wallJumpingDirection;
    public float wallJumpingTime = 0.2f;
    private float wallJumpingCounter;
    public float wallJumpingDuration = 0.4f;
    private Vector2 wallJumpingPower = new Vector2(8f, 10f);

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform wallCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        WallSlide();
        WallJump();

        if (!isWallJumping)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isWallJumping)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private bool IsWalled()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(wallCheck.position, 0.2f, wallLayer);
    }

    private void WallSlide()
    {
        if (IsWalled() && !IsGrounded() && horizontal != 0f)
        {
            isWallSliding = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -wallSlidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
        }
        else
        {
            isWallSliding = false;
        }
    }

    private void WallJump()
    {
        if (isWallSliding)
        {
            isWallJumping = false;
            wallJumpingDirection = -transform.localScale.x;
            wallJumpingCounter = wallJumpingTime;

            CancelInvoke(nameof(StopWallJumping));
        }
        else
        {
            wallJumpingCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && wallJumpingCounter > 0f)
        {
            isWallJumping = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(wallJumpingDirection * wallJumpingPower.x, wallJumpingPower.y);
            wallJumpingCounter = 0f;

            if (transform.localScale.x != wallJumpingDirection)
            {
                isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
                Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
                localScale.x *= -1f;
                transform.localScale = localScale;
            }

            Invoke(nameof(StopWallJumping), wallJumpingDuration);
        }
    }

    private void StopWallJumping()
    {
        isWallJumping = false;
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Some screenshots of related things.

[Wall Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOuIR.png)

[Ground Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8EzV.png)

[Player RigidBody2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elc6g.png)

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvMWW.png)

I've tried using his original script, and watched the tutorial over multiple times. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be a really great help!

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way to fix!
I wasn't using a material for my rigid body 2d, and I had to apply one that had no friction, which is why it was sticking to the walls.